# Bootstrap data table tr doesn't fire onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Please refer to example here:
http://jsfiddle.net/c0kackzw/

A table goes like this:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="example">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Rendering engine</th>
        <th>Browser</th>
        <th>Platform(s)</th>
        <th>Engine version</th>
        <th>CSS grade</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="reportRow odd gradeX">
        <td>Trident</td>
        <td>Internet
             Explorer 4.0</td>
        <td>Win 95+</td>
        <td class="center"> 4</td>
        <td class="center">X</td>
    </tr>
```

When you click a row on the first page, click function works but it doesn't work when you are on the other pages:

```
$('.reportRow').click(function(){
alert('mm');
});
```

and all rows has reportRow class. If i add onclick='myFunc' to all tr s it works. But I don't want to use that. How do I make the other way work?

Comment: What other way? You said that both approaches work.

Comment: Sorry. Edited the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use event delegation:
It will apply event on the dynamic elements.

```
$('#example').on('click', '.reportRow', function () {
    alert('mm');
});
```

Ref: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/c0kackzw/1/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are only binding click event to the first page rows, but not the second, and etc.

In this case you need to delegate click event to the table itself. It means that instead of binding separate event handler to every row, you bind the only one on some wrapping container (like table in your case; you could also use `document` or `body`). Click events occurred inside of this container will eventually bubble to the container you bound handler to, where you can handle it.

```
$('#example').on('click', '.reportRow', function(){
    alert('mm');
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/c0kackzw/2/